# swift ios 9 app not in Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

I had swift camera code that worked on ios 8 and xcode 6.
I called AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) but my application does not show up in [Settings -> privacy -> Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vFqo.png)
(but other apps show up)
[image: camera]

After updating to ios 9 and xcode 7 Can't get camera permission work.
I searched 2 days on google and stackoverflow.

---

**problem**

I imported AVFoundation and called AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) always get AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied

1. my application does not show up in Settings -> privacy -> Camera
2. Camera is black
3. requestAccessForMediaType does not open popup
4. authorizationStatusForMediaType is always Denied

Main problem is No 1. I think if I can get my app on Settings -> privacy -> Camera then other problems are solved.

**thigns I tried**

- child class of UIImagePickerController
- Removed and reinstalled my app
- Changed Bundle ID
- Changed iphone date to 3 days in future
- called requestAccessForMediaType in main thread

---

- Xcode 7
- ios 9.0 9.1
- iphone 5, 5s, 6
- swift 2.1

---

**my code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        cameraView()
}

func checkCamera() {
        let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        switch authStatus {
        case AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:
            print("AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized")
        case AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            print("AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied")
        case AVAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            print("AVAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined")
        case AVAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            print("AVAuthorizationStatus.Restricted")
        default:
            print("AVAuthorizationStatus.Default")
        }

    }

func cameraView(){
        // session
        let mySession : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        var myDevice : AVCaptureDevice? //= AVCaptureDevice()
        let myImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

        let audioCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
        let audioInput = (try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioCaptureDevice[0] as! AVCaptureDevice))  as AVCaptureInput

        for device in devices {
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back){
                myDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }

        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        print(status ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
        print(status ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
        print(status ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Restricted)
        print(status.rawValue)

        if status !=  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {

            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
                if granted == false {
                    // Camera not Authorized
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        print("Camera not Authorized")
                        self.checkCamera()
                        return
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a new pair of Info.plist values, same as the String for Location Services would be in iOS8:

Just set your description string for those.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't try that one. I added below code to info.plist. But still not appearing in privacy setting

`<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Camera</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Photos</string>`

result is AVAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined at start.
then when i ask permission with requestAccessForMediaType
result is AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction.
It didn't work right when i added those keys to my project.
So I created new project and added those keys and copied info.plist file to my project and it worked.